# Linking to External Resources in jsfiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

Can someone explain how to find external resources for creating jsfiddle examples? I've been looking on github and plugin author's websites but there must be a standard method to get links to these files.

This example of the [masonry layout](http://jsfiddle.net/WebEnvelopment/DD6g2/):
However, I scavenged the resource from David Dsandro's dropbox.

```
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1000295/jquery.masonry.min.js
```

I got the fiddle's masonry layout to work but linking by scavenging doesn't sound ethical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing. All you can do in the `External Resources` section is to provide a url to the library/plugin/css you want. The hotlinking ethics principles applies in jsfiddle as in any other website.

You can get that link in the traditional way, looking into the library's author site, or in a cdn. For example, [cdnjs](http://cdnjs.com/) is a great site where you will possibly find the libs you need (including mansonry in this case).  [jsdelivr](http://www.jsdelivr.com/) is another cdn hosting lots of libs that I've just discovered thanks to this question.

Take into account that you already have some plugins built-in in the `Frameworks & Extensions` section.